# Зачем создавать свой сервер на nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Я недавно начал изучать nodejs. Сразу возник вопрос. Во всех примерах которые есть в сети разработчики создают свой сервер на основе express или ещё чего-нибудь. Почему при работе с php используется внешний сервер apache или nginx, а в приложении на node обязательно создают что-то своё? Как потом деплоить такое приложение? В случае с nginx я бы мог в конфиге указать доменное имя и в какую директорию должен смотреть сервер, как быть с нодой?

Comment: apache - это условно говоря такой же сервер что и у ноды, а вместе с nginx обычно используется php-fpm, который тоже такой же сервер (условно). Вообще вам ничего не мешает использовать сервер ноды совместно с nginx :)

Comment: Хороший вопрос, я присоединяюсь и тоже хочу знать - если есть нормальный web-сервер и php, зачем nodejs

Comment: @wirtwelt вопрос о нужности php вообще не должен стоять — он кривой, медленный и ни для чего нормального не годится

Comment: @andreymal, у `PHP` Есть проблемы, множество, которые очень бесят, но не на одном языке, вы никогда, не поднимите блог за 10 минут, не используя фреймворки, который сможет работать с +1000 пользователь одновременно... Другов вопрос, нужен ли кому-то этот блог.

Comment: Я кажется начал обсуждение в комментариях, прошу прощения. Я просто много лет писал на PHP вполне себе рабочие проекты и наблюдал за сменой версий с 4.3 до 7.2. Сейчас вокруг наплодилось куча модных фреймворков всех мастей и окрасов, и я чувствую себя мамонтом и не понимаю что происходит ) Поэтому мне уже давно интересно - зачем это все ))

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов за 10 минут можно только успеть взять готовый блог типа вордпресса, а он сам по себе фреймворк. Так что ваш комментарий мне не очень понятен (впрочем, я начал оффтопик не по теме вопроса, предлагаю не продолжать или продолжать не здесь :)

Comment: Можно это как-то удалить, Андрей? Портим нормальный вопрос ((

Comment: Ничего мы не портим. Обычное обсуждение, которые не дошло до чата. Ненадо ничего удалять. :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Как я понял сервер на ноде это просто альтернатива тому же nginx, просто кому что больше нравится

Answer (score 0):

У `NodeJS` Есть ряд приймуещств перед веб-серверами, такие как асинхронность, стандартная из коробки готовность к работе по `WebSockets`, производительность в ряде случаев будет выше. К тому-же на `NodeJS` Мы полностью имеем контроль над происходящим, когда в `PHP` Мы ограничены одной лишь сессией, а память между сессиями реализуем не по самым безопасным `cookie`. Как говориться, все под свои задачи, если у вас есть цель написать высокопроизводительное веб-приложение, используйте `NodeJS`, для вещей где такой контроль будет избыточен, можно взять тот же `PHP` Или `Django`, они работает из под веб-сервера. Также можно вполне совмещать веб-сервер вроде `Apache` И приложения на `NodeJS`, например использовать веб-сервер для того чтобы он отдавал статические файлы с сервера(картинки).

Деплоить все на сервера, легко с помощью таких систем как `Docker`, докер это кстати одна из тех вещей, которую необходимо знать несмотря на профессию.